# scala custom traversable of Seq[A]

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

I am trying to make my Graph to implement Traversable for it's edges.
I have a type of edge called Edge[Node, EdgeType].
My edge is a final case class.
The code looks like this:

```
class Graph[Node, Type] extends Traverasble[Edge[Node, Type]]
```

I saw [this post](https://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-custom-traversable.html) about creating a custom Traversable, but I can't make it work.
My Graph knows it's element, Edge, but not its parameter type, Node and EdgeType. I couldn't make the Factory to understand those generics.

```
object Graph extends TraversableFactory[Graph] {
    implicit def canBuildFrom[A<:Edge[_,_]]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Graph[_]] = new GenericCanBuildFrom[A]
    def newBuilder[A<:Edge[_,_]] = new ListBuffer[A] mapResult (x => new Graph(x:_*))
}
```

I tried to use higherKinds, but I don't see how solve it with same either.

Do you know how I can solve this? This problem returns everytime a class with some generics extends Traversable that it's Elem is a composition of the class generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve by implementing custom `TraversableFactory`. Those machinery is there to support generic collections i.e. collections that can store  elements of ***arbitrary*** type. This is important because the supported methods include methods that can change type of the element such as `.map`. What it the expected type of the `intCol` and `mapped` in the following code:

```
val graph: Graph[SomeNode, SomeType] = ???
val intCol = graph.companion.empty[Int]
val mapped = graph.map(edge => 42) // yes fixed value just for an example
```

`intCol` and `mapped` should definitely be some subtype of `Traversable[Int]`. Can you `Graph` represent such an object? If no, then your `Graph` is not a generic collection and should not have a custom `companion` `TraversableFactory` object.

P.S. Since you didn't provide any description of what you are really trying to achieve, it is hard to guess, but it might be that what you really want is inheriting from `TraversableLike` (or `IterableLike`) rather than `Traversable`. The main difference is that `TraversableLike` do not define `companion` so can represent a collection specific for just one type.

Comment: Thanks you very! Its look like I jumped too far and I only need to implement TraversableLike or IterableLike as you said. It was really confusing with all the Like and not Like collection.